# FRED rest API in python

Tags: java, python, python-2.7

We are using [FRED](http://wit.istc.cnr.it/stlab-tools/fred/) to convert plain data to RDF/XML format. We have found JAVA code for this online can u provide us with the PYTHON code.
JAVA code that I found is :

```
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;

public class TestGet
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        try 
    {
            Client client = Client.create();
            WebResource webResource = client.resource("http://wit.istc.cnr.it/stlab-tools/fred/");
            ClientResponse response = webResource.queryParam("text", "He is a good boy").accept("application/rdf+xml").get(ClientResponse.class);
            if (response.getStatus() != 200) 
            {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "+response.getStatus());
            }
            String output = response.getEntity(String.class);
            System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
            System.out.println(output);
        } 
    catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such a simple case, [`urllib2`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) is probably the easiest choice.

```
import urllib2
import urllib # needed for url-encoding
par = {"text": "He is a good boy"}
headers={"Accept" : "application/rdf+xml"}
request = urllib2.Request(
    "http://wit.istc.cnr.it/stlab-tools/fred/?" + urllib.urlencode(par),
    headers=headers)
contents = urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
print contents
```

Or maybe you'd like to go with [`Requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/), which is way cooler if things get more complicated:

```
import requests
par = {"text": "He is a good boy"}
headers={"Accept" : "application/rdf+xml"}
r = requests.get("http://wit.istc.cnr.it/stlab-tools/fred/",
    data=par, headers=headers)
print r["text"]
```

Comment: I am getting this error on my system when running the first code

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "Example.py", line 5, in <module>
        "http://wit.istc.cnr.it/stlab-tools/fred/?" + urllib2.urlencode(par),
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'urlencode'